# Python Fibonacci sequence and sequence unpacking

Tags: python-2.7

I'm processing the fibonacci sequence by iteration. I expected the following two functions to provide the same results, but they do not.

Example 1 (returns Fibonacci sequence as desired):

```
def run():
    for x in range(0,20):    
        fib(x)

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    print a

run()
```

Example 1 results:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Example 2 (without sequence unpacking):

```
def run():
    for x in range(0,20):    
        fib(x)

def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(n):
        a = b
        b = a + b 
    print a

run()
```

Example 2 results:

```
0
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
```

Specifically, why is...

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

Different than...

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

`a, b = b, a + b` is first evaluating the right side of the `=` and then assigning it to the left side. I.e. the results in `a` and `b` would be based on the calculation with the previous values (before this line). While the second code is doing exactly what is written sequentially, while the second line is evaluating with the values obtained in the first line.

Comment: Thank you. For clarification, what might a multi-line solution to `a, b = b, a + b` look like?

Comment: For example you can introduce a temporary variable to store the previous `a` result: `c = a`
       `a = b`
       `b = c + b`

Answer (score 0):

The first returns the result of the evaluation of right-hand value (a + b) and uses it for assignment.  That is, evaluate (a+b) and THEN assign (a=b) and (b=result)
Whereas the second overwrites the value in "a" before it can be used in your equation.

That is, in looping through the following:

```
a=b
b=a+b
```

The results are:

```
a = 0, b = (0 + 1), print a: 0
a = 1, b = (1 + 1), print a: 1
a = 2, b = (2 + 2), print a: 2
a = 4, b = (4 + 4), print a: 4
```

What you need is a temporary return value because you don't want to update the values of a or b until you have evaluated the statement a+b.

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(n):
        temp = a + b
        a, b = b, temp
    print a
```